# Python Addition Decimal Divisions

Tags: python

I have a range of `Decimal` numbers which I am dividing.  But when I sum the result of the divisions, I get an unexpected answer.

Consider the code below:

```
from decimal import Decimal
a = Decimal('3.00')
a1 = Decimal('15.00')

b = Decimal('4.00')
b1 = Decimal('16.00')

c = Decimal('7.00')
c1 = Decimal('31.00')

a2 = a / a1
b2 = b / b1
c2 = c / c1

c == a + b #True
c1 == a1 + b1 #True
c2 == a2 + b2 #False
```

Why is `c2 == a2 + b2` evaluating `False`?

Comment: Because math? Those are not the same number.

Comment: Check your math, not a fault of Decimal

Comment: c2 is about 0.225. That's not the same as 0.2 + 0.25 in any programming language.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a misunderstanding of how math works, not a programming problem.

Comment: Because `a2 + b2 == Decimal('0.45')` but `c2 == Decimal('0.2258064516129032258064516129')`?

Comment: Because sum of divisions is not the same as division of sums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a2 + b2 = a/a1 + b/b1 = (a*b1 + b*a1)/a1*b1
```

does not equal

```
c2 = c / c1 = (a+b) / (a1 + b1)
```